# FancyBox 2 Ajax window size control

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am working with fancybox2 and having trouble getting my fancy window to resize to the content. It seems to just stretch the entire width of the page...

http://www.mniac.com/rogue24/the-craft/press.php

Click **read more** on the initial press article

You will see I have the content in a container with an absolute width. I have tried every variation of setting I can find and nothing seems to be working...

This is what I am using:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
                    'type':'ajax',
                    'autoScale':'false',
                    'autoDimensions':'true'
                });
```

This script worked for me:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
                    'type':'ajax',
                    'autoSize': false,
                    'width': 800
                });
```

'fitToView': false - made the popup crazy wide, far beyond the screen's limit. 'autoSize': true - is a default value so nothing changed with that. I found you can set the width by doing what is done above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#article-container` (from your ajax content) has this `css` rule

```
#article-container {
  width: 50%;
}
```

... that is not absolute, is half of the parent container (fancybox) so even if you set a fixed `width` for fancybox, let's say `600px`, your content inside of it will be only `300px width`.

Anyway, **the main issue** you have is that neither `autoScale` or `autoDimensions` are valid API options for fancybox v2.x .... fancybox v2.x options are new and not compatible with previous (v1.3.x) versions.

Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs for the right API options .... in your case I think you meant to use `fitToView` (`autoScale` in v1.3.x) and `autoSize` (`autoDimensions` in v1.3.x) like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'type': 'ajax',
    'fitToView': false,
    'autoSize': true
});​
```

BTW, **notice** that neither Boolean (`true`/`false`) or integer values go with quotes ... that would make your script fail.